# Using python3 tifffile writing tiff image stacks unreadable

Tags: python-3.x, tiff

I have a 3D numpy array storing 16bit intensities for a 3D image. I would like to use tifffile module to create a image sequence along z-axis:

```
import numpy as np
import tifffile as tiff

data = np.zeros((x_axis, y_axis, z_axis)) #just a sample
for z in range(z_axis):
  tiff.imsave(str(z)+'.tiff', data[:, :, z])
  image = tiff.imread(str(z)+'.tiff')
  print(np.array_equal(image, data[:, :, z])) #always print True
```

The last line above always print "True", which means that tiff.imsave and tiff.imread should be okay. However, the output .tiff files are not readable by free software such as Slicer 3D or GIMP 2. I tried to download several 3D tiff examples from the internet and those softwares are able to open them correctly. As a result, I'm wondering if I have misused the tifffile package.

With 3D slicer, it shows that it has loaded the image sequence. But the Volume module and Volume Rendering module do not show the volume. With GIMP2, it just shows nothing.

Please give me a hand, thanks!

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: No, I'm using python 3.4.5

Comment: I have figured it out. The data type of the numpy array should be "float32" such that the tiff sequence can be correctly loaded and rendered.